# Laravel 5.6 PHPUnit error's no longer logged to file

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

While upgrading Laravel from `5.5` to `5.6` I've been running into an issue where `PHPUnit exceptions/tests` are no longer logging to file.

I'm using https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing as part of the testing framework.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and if so, did you find a way to continue logging exceptions to file while testing?

Comment: Laravel 5.5 uses PHPUnit 6, where Laravel 5.6 uses PHPUnit 7. Maybe there is some config change you missed for PHPUnit?

Comment: @Loek nothing in the changelog suggests a logging difference https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/ChangeLog-7.0.md